# Is it possible to send a Windows 8 System Repair Disc over the Internet?

Tags: windows-8, bootable-media

My friend's Laptop crashed and now I need to send a Windows 8 System repair to him over the internet since there is no other Windows 8 machine there.

Is this possible? Specially since Windows 8 requires to write it on a DVD or USB flash drive... how do you guys suggest I get it to him?

I'm thinking:
1) Create the recovery/repair usb drive here locally.. 
2) use a tool to create an ISO image of that usb drive 
3) send that ISO over to him
4) use the same tool to restore or create a bootable USB drive from that ISO image i sent.

Do I need to go through all these? or shall I just send him the contents of the USB flash drive? (I'm not familiar with Windows 8 boot directives, but I know on Windows 7 the flash drive needs to be made "bootable" for sure.)

Comment: Sure;  Just create an .iso of the disk and send it to your friend.  Be sure its the same version of Windows 8.  This means if your running Windows 8.1 then it cannot be used on your friends 8.0 machine.

Comment: what do you mean send the whole disk? he's in a different location and i need to send it VIRTUALLY though... not the disk itself. can i just send the contents of the disk as is?

Comment: I actually suggested that you can create an .iso of the recovery disk and send that to him. There are tons of free and paid file sharing websites that would allow you to share the file with your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a restore USB - create an *img* image -I use the [win32 disk imager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) - run as admin, and use *read* to create the image and *write* apply an image to the disk. This is a full bit by bit copy of the drive so to reduce bandwidth usage, *compress* the image with 7zip or something.